# Regular Borel Measures equivalent definition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, gn.general-topology

Please help me understand how the below definition is equivalent to the standard  definition of regularity which says that a measure is regular if for which every measurable set can be approximated from above by an open measurable set and from below by a compact measurable set.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure

Second def.
"μ is regular whenever A is in the domain of definition of Borel algebra and δ>0, there are closed and open sets C and U. such that C⊂A⊂U and |μ|(U\ C)<ϵ."

Comment: Not all definitions of regular measures are equivalent, so you should be more explicit with what the "standard definition" is. Also, this is not really research mathematics, so you might want to ask this where such questions are appropriat, such as http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Michale, I have added the definition which I was referring to.. 

Comment: They are not equivalent.  

Comment: ...unless there is some additional information (such as complete separable metric) so that closed sets may be approximated from inside by compact sets.